# How to exactly write previous month in google excel

Tags: google-sheets

I need date *today minus one month* formula in google excel.
I've already tried:

```
'=(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2))+1
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
=EDATE(TODAY(),-1)
```

Comment: What is the error. It could be your country code. Try =EDATE(today();-1). (replaced ',' with ';')

Comment: yes this formule is worked =EDATE(today();-1) +1 from me :) I accept youre answer but don't forget to change it please @EdNelson

Answer (score 0):

`=DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)), MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)), day (TODAY()))`

same day of month as today, month before.

Comment: What is the error. It could be your country code. Try =EDATE(today();-1). (replaced ',' with ';')